# Alert the user about required iOS version while installing iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

I'm not sure if this is something can be achieved in coding level:

Display an Alert View to the user about required iOS version if the current iOS version is not compatible with the installing app?

I'm doing Wireless Adhoc Distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the app is being installed, you don't have an event to display such alert view since app is not yet started. You can limit your `Deployment target` of your xcode project to only allow to install app if it compatible with the version. If app is incompatible with iOS version, it won't install.

E.g.,

```
1. Deployment target 9.0
   Device OS 8.0

App won't install

2. Deployment target 7.0
   Device OS 8.0

App will install
```